# How to organize a web app with multiple SPA(Single Page App)s in ExpressJS Server?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

The Reactjs is very good using with Redux. However, if we were to build a large web app, only one Single Page App is often not the best choice.

What I think, is to combine traditional MVC framework( like the Expressjs MVC framework ) and Reactjs in one website (often multiple Redux-React apps).

In this website, I may have multiple WebPack bundle files, that is ,this site may contain multipe SPAs(single page apps). I do not know how to organize this in my Nodejs server (Express).

Do I need to have multiple WebPack Configurations files and have multiple WebPack instances running to produce mutilple bundle files (and how can I run multiple WebPack instances in my ExpressJS server?)? Or can I write a single WebPack Configuration file and have multiple bundle files output?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that one SPA is not the best choice, please clarify? I have the opposite opinion, that SPA is more convenient for development and support. I just think you're going wrong direction

Comment: @krvital:The concern of SPA for me is that when the website is too large, the initial load of bundle.js file will be too big, thus making first fetch/visit of the website slow. Do you have good solution for this?

Comment: I propose two solitions
1) Server side rendering
2) Code splitting by webpack and dynamic routes

Comment: @krvital  Yes, react-router dynamic route is a good solution. SSR is a good solution too. But it seems the best practive of these 2 solutions are not stable by now. And I find that, large sites, like github, youtube, facebook, seems they are not SPAs. If SPA is the best way, why would not they use it?

Comment: I think because those sites was too large for global changes when solutions like this comes in production. Also I don't think that code splitting is not stable, SSR maybe

Comment: I agree. Hope we can see more large Reactjs production sites.

Comment: I have a case like this. We have multiple products in our single project. One product might be in react with react router, one product will be in VueJS with vue router. In such a case we might need an express to handle multiple SPA, is it not?  For us migrating everything to a single front end stack is expensive, even if we do so it will take some time. Can anyone suggest an approach? @VitaliiKravtsov